# Why am I getting a Group By error in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

My goal is to write a SQL statement to find out the total purchase (in terms of dollar amount) of each customer. The result should have three columns: customer name, contact name, the purchase dollar amount.
This is the statement I have thus far:

```
SELECT
  SUM(quantity*item_price) AS PurchaseDollarAmount, 
  cust_contact, 
  contact_name 
FROM Customers, OrderItems 
ORDER BY cust_name;
```

I receive the following error:

> ERROR 1140 (42000): In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression #2 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'cisc5500test.Customers.cust_contact'; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

I'm still new to MySQL. Can you guys help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: You need to add the `GROUP BY` clause.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need `JOIN` conditions.  A Cartesian product makes no sense.

Second, I'm guessing there is another table.

Third, you have no `GROUP BY`, but you should.

The query is something like this:

```
SELECT cust_name, SUM(oi.quantity * oi.item_price) AS PurchaseDollarAmount
FROM Customers c JOIN
     Orders o
     ON c.customerId = o.customerId JOIN
     OrderItems oi
     ON oi.orderId = o.orderId
GROUP BY cust_name;
```

Comment: SELECT cust_name, SUM(quantity*item_price) AS PurchaseDollarAmount FROM Customers JOIN Orders ON Customers = Customers JOIN OrderItems ON OrderItems = OrderItems GROUP BY cust_name; I'm now getting this error: ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'OrderItems' in 'on clause